# Json date format conversion subtracting 1 day

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, date

The date format i receive from JSON is like this :-

```
/Date(1412101800000)/
```

When i convert this into dateformat, i get 1 day minus.

I am using following code :-

```
var dateFormat = new Date(parseInt(obj['DATEOFJOINING'].substr(6))).toISOString().substr(0, 10);

dateFormat results in 2014-09-30
```

The Original Date which comes from `Db` is `2014-10-01`

Why is this happening? How to get perfect date?

Comment: May be because of the difference in timezones of server and client PC.

Answer (score 3):

It's a timestamp.

```
new Date(parseInt('/Date(1412101800000)/'.substr(6)));
```

Just set a right **timezone.**

```
var dateFormat = new Date(parseInt('/Date(1412101800000)/'.substr(6)));
dateFormat.setTime( dateFormat.getTime() + dateFormat.getTimezoneOffset()*60*1000  );
```

Date in your timezone*: 30/09/2014 19:30:00
Date in Los Angeles*: 30/09/2014 11:30:00
Date in Berlin* :30/09/2014 19:30:00
Date in Beijing*: 01/10/2014 01:30:00
Date in New York* :30/09/2014 13:30:00

For example

```
var dateFormat = new Date(parseInt('/Date(1412101800000)/'.substr(6)));
    dateFormat.setTime( dateFormat.getTime() + dateFormat.getTimezoneOffset()*(-10*100000));
```

Date {Wed Oct 01 2014 12:10:00 GMT+0100 (BST)}

Comment: I tried ur code... Still shows me date minus 1 day.!

Comment: I am using angular ng-grid...when i edit the date field...it shows `Tue Sep 30 2014 18:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`

Comment: @Anup you need to put your timezone.Just replace values 60*100

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the clients timezone.
 Use [`Date.prototype.getTimezoneOffset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset) to get the offset:

```
var date = new Date(1412101800000);
var gmtDate = new Date(date.valueOf() + date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000);
```

Comment: No Luck...Shows date minus 1 day..!

Answer (score 0):

As @madforstrength commented, it uses the offset from GMT.
To get the offset in minutes you can try:

```
var d = new Date()
var n = d.getTimezoneOffset();
```

and adjust for your local time.

You can see a reference [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp).